# How to bootcamp on Mac late 2011 OSX El Captian

Tags: macos

Iv been trying to bootcamp on my Macbook Pro Late 2011. My problem is that the bootcamp assistent is asking for a disc. I burned the iso file on a dvd but when i run bootcamp it still gives me the same message?

I have OS X El Captain.

Would really appreciate some help, been googling for ages...

Thanks

Comment: Why would anyone install BootCamp? Surely it is better to use VirtualBox which is free, which can run any OS, which you can easily remove, which runs at the same time as OSX and whose Virtual Machines can be moved to any other machine and consist of only a single file - rather than dinking around with your disk partitioning and only being able to run your Mac under Windows and only being able to do one OS at a time? Just asking...

Comment: Yea Virtual box is easier but is not as good at running games as when its the actual Bootcamp OS Running its better (In Virtual Box you can't play GTA V)